# Creating userbot for parsing/forwarding content from one group to my own channel

Tags: parsing, telegram-bot, telethon

```
from tokenize import Token
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon import utils


api_id = 
api_hash = ''
bot = Token('')
client = TelegramClient('Xparser', api_id, api_hash)

entity = '-1001201387948'
message_ids = '-1001605164255'
from_entity = '-1001605164255'



client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Tried telethon, but cannot understand how to track and forward posts. I have my api_id, api_hash and bot Token.
PLEASE HELP with a script to track channel when there appears smth new forward to my own one(usually it's pictures and a little bit of text).

Answer (score 0):

using [new message event handler](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.newmessage.NewMessage),

if message is from that channel, try [forward it](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.forward_messages)

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
def handler(event):
  if (event.chat_id == channle_id):
    text = event.raw_text 
    ##parse your text
    client.send_messages(your_channel, newtext)
```

Comment: Could you please show how it does(eventhough a little bit part of code. Because i can't understand how to work with documentation, such things as Args e t c.

Comment: @WhiteHappy is it possible to edit messages while parsing? f.e there is a price of 10$, but when bot copies this to my channel it should be 12$.

Comment: You can get the event.raw_text element from the new message event
and then try edit it and use client.send_message() to send it to your channel